# calling a function on jQuery model dialog close

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I have a small problem related to the jQuery modal dialog box. The scenario is such:

I have to call a function when i exit or close the dialog box by pressing the cross[x] button on the top right.

Comment: jQuery UI? or what? If yes - here is the [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-beforeClose)

Answer (score 6):

[Documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-close)

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({
  close: function( event, ui ) {
        //write your function here or call function here
  }
});
```

Comment: does not work for the [X] button I think. This will create a `button` in the UI.

Answer (score 3):

**Solution 1:**
Initialize the dialog with the close callback specified:

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({
      close: function( event, ui ) {**functionCall();**}
    });
```

**Solution 2:**
Bind an event listener to the dialogclose event:

```
$( ".selector" ).on( "dialogclose", function( event, ui ) { functionCall();} );
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the 'close' callback when you create the dialog box. Here is the documentation and an example:

http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-close

Answer (score 0):

```
//Image tag
<img src="" id="cross">

//jquery
$('#cross').click( function () {
// your function definition goes here 
});
```